# Subroutine fails to take the variables inside td tag using perl cgi?

Tags: perl, cgi

In this part of Perl cgi code  `$_` variable failed to print its contents inside `<td>` tag using Perl cgi?

```
sub do_work {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $content;    

    while ( my $line= <$fh> ) {
        my @name1 = grep {$_ =~ m/^\[/} $line;
        s/\W//g for @name1;
        $content .= join '', @name1;
    }

    return $content;
}

sub do_task {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $load;
    while(my $firstline = <$fh>) {
        $firstline =~ s/.*=//g;
        my @words = split /,., $firstline;
        my $add = 0;
        $load1 .= join("\n", @words);   
    }

    return $load1;  
}

sub layout {
    my ($load, @words = @_;
    my $add = 0;

    print << "EOF";
    <html><body><table>
    <tr>
    <th>s.no</th>
    <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    EOF

    foreach(@words) {
        $add++;
        print<<"EOF"
        <tr>
        <td>$add</td>
        <td>$_</td>
    EOF
    }

    print <<"EOF"
    </table></body></html>
    EOF
}
```

Description :

1. To read the @words again and again i had used foreach loop. Here `@words` are read from the previous subroutine. I tried to load the same array contents into the `<td>` tag. But from my code it is not getting the into the foreach? Because of what mistake it is not loading its contents.

Expected output:

From `$load1` it got the following output:

```
hardware
software
os
```

So i tried to print it in table i.e inside `<td>` tag so i had used the foreach loop to take default value.

Now i expect my output should be as follows:

```
s.no   name
1      Hardware
2      Software
3      os
```

Comment: This is not your real code. It has syntax errors. Please include your **real code**! And while you're at it, please also include example data to reproduce the problem, and explain what output you expect.

Comment: real code is too big thats why i had added the part of the code where it shows problem. @simbabque

Comment: added expected output. @simbabque

Comment: Your indentation is horrible and your brace placement is inconsistent. If you want people to read and understand your code, please take the time to make it as easy to read as possible.

Comment: I know that your code is too large to share. But the code that you give us should at least compile. Having just gone through your code to make it readable I spot at least two lines with obvious syntax errors - `my @words = split /,., $firstline;` and `my ($load, @words = @_;`.  If you can't take the time to make your code even compile, then why should we spend time looking at it?

Comment: Make sure you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in each module/script:  [Perldoc: Safety Net](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Safety-net)

Answer (score 1):

The `EOF` marker for the HEREDOC needs to be all the way on the left. It cannot have leading whitespace. Because of that, there should be a syntax error because the rest of your code is not recognized as code by the parser.

It should look like that.

```
sub layout
{

    my($load)=@_;
    my @words=@_;
    my $add=0;
    print << "EOF";
    <html><body><table>
    <tr>
    <th>s.no</th>
    </tr>
EOF

    foreach(@words)
    {
    $add++;
    print<<"EOF"
    <tr>
    <td>$add</td>
    <td>$_</td>
EOF

    }
    print <<"EOF"
    </table></body></html>
EOF

}
```

Indented HEREDOCs will probably be available with Perl 5.26. A new feature was released with the development version [5.25.7](http://search.cpan.org/~reneeb/perl-5.25.10/pod/perl5257delta.pod#Indented_Here-documents) that introduces new syntax `<<~"EOF"`. But you likely do not have that version, or a newer one.

---

In addition to that, you are putting the first argument of the function in `$load`, but also into `@words`. That's probably wrong. That should be `my ($load, @words) = @_`.

Comment: After Indentation also i find same problem. @simbabque

Comment: added expected output   @simbabque

Comment: why the <tr> is not closed inside the foreach loop @simbabque

Comment: @insite because I copied it from the question, and it's missing there too ;)

Comment: Still am not loaded with the contents inside td tag . @simbabque

Comment: @insite both me and others have asked you in comments on the question to at least make the code there compile, and to include example input. If you do not do that we're not going to help you, because we can't. You might think that it's just the example, so it doesn't matter, but it does. Most of the times you will find the problem yourself when trying to reduce it to a minimal example. Often the problem is not where you think it is. I am willing to help you, for free, on my day off (there's a bank holiday in my country today), but only if you help, too.